# Bash re-assignment of value to variable "command not found"

Tags: bash

Any ideas why this is happening? Why do I have to manually explicitly reassign the variable but can't do it if I have another variable in the name of the variable?

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

a_1=1
a_2=1

for temp in 1 2
do
    a_$temp="2"
    echo $((a_$temp))
done

a_1=2
a_2=2
echo $a_1
echo $a_2
```

OUTPUT:

```
[dgupta@della4 Rates_Of_Quenching]$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 8: a_1=2: command not found
1
./test.sh: line 8: a_2=2: command not found
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
a_$temp="2"
```

Use:

```
declare a_$temp="2"
```

to create variable with dynamic name.

Answer (score 2):

As far as bash is concerned, you are trying to execute the command `'a_1=2'`, rather than perform an assignment. You can get around this by using [`declare`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html), or its synonym `typeset`:

```
'a_1=2'                       # bash: a_1=2: command not found
typeset 'a_1=2' 
echo $a_1                     # 2
declare 'a_1=3'
echo $a_1                     # 3
```

While it is possible to use `declare`, you might want to take advantage of bash arrays (which have been around since bash version 2) rather than using variables with numerical suffixes:

```
a=(1 1)
echo ${a[0]}                  # 1
echo ${a[1]}                  # 1
for i in 0 1; do a[i]=2; done
echo ${a[0]}                  # 2
echo ${a[1]}                  # 2
```

Comment: +1, but (a) `bash` considers `typeset` obsolete (it still has its place if maximum portability is required) and (b) your inclusion of a prompt string (`bash-4.3$`) both creates visual noise and makes it harder to copy-paste your code for verification (it's commendable to state the `bash` version your code was run on, but that could be done separately, although, depending on the feature discussed, stating the version may not be necessary at all, if a feature was introduced a loooong time ago).

Comment: You're welcome; I was actually thinking of _not using a prompt string at all_ (even just `$`), as it makes copy-pasting any _sequence_ of commands cumbersome. I know that `$` is seductive, because it is widely used to symbolize a prompt, whereas I know of no equally well-known symbol to indicate _output_ (is there one?). However, I think on SO reversing the logic is beneficial: _no_ prefix for the _commands_, and some indicator for _output_. One - not very elegant - way around this is to place output in a _separate_ code snippet.

Comment: @mklement0 I agree with your thoughts. For a longer script, I would normally show the output separately. I've edited to show the output of the commands in comments, which at least means that the commands can be directly copy-pasted.

Comment: Good idea; placing the output in _comments_ is a simpler alternative.

Comment: @mklement0 of course, my answer would have been three times as well appreciated if I'd instead displayed no output, provided no explanation but _crucially_ got there first. Not that I'm bitter ;) Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: :) Thanks for _listening_ to my feedback. Truthfully, different styles of answers are useful to different audiences at different times. The quick-and-dirty answers are sometimes more useful if you're a newbie and just want an answer without getting confused by TMI; however, over time a more thorough answer like yours may also find its audience.